# Is it possible to pass custom argument to setState callback function?

Tags: reactjs, callback

Is there a way to pass argument to setState(function(prevState, props, custom_rgument)?

```
removeTodo(evt) {
    this.setState((prevState, props, evt) => ({
        todoList: [...prevState.todoList.slice(0, evt), ...prevState.todoList.slice(evt + 1)]
    }))
}
```

Or the only way to achieve this is to work with state?

```
removeTodo() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        todoList: [...prevState.todoList.slice(0, this.state.index), ...prevState.todoList.slice(this.state.index + 1)]
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be a need to pass the `evt` parameter to the `setState` function. It's available in the scope anyways.

```js
removeTodo(evt) {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    todoList: [
      ...prevState.todoList.slice(0, evt),
      ...prevState.todoList.slice(evt + 1)
    ]
  }));
}
```

Comment: Another question: is this the correct way to remove an item from a non-mutable array? Because it deletes correctly the first and the last element, but if I try to remove an element in the middle of the array, all the element after are deleted too.